# Android Studio 3.4 Android Wear SDK 22

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I have downloaded and installed Android Studio 3.4.2. When I create a new Wear OS project the only available SDKs are 23 and later. I want to support older devices with SKD 22 or 23. I realise there has something to do with Android Wear converted to WearOS. How can I enable support for older SKDs? Is it only related to the WearOS templates?

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no Wear 1.x device that run on SDK earlier than 23, that's why the minimum SDK version available is SDK 23

For more infos:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging

Comment: So if you are targeting 22 you use the normal activities and adjust them for small screens or there is a special kind of activity/template to use?

Comment: There is no reason to target SDK 22 since no Wear device uses it. Targeting SDK 23 should be fine